# Hide UIMenuController

Tags: iphone

Want to hide **UIMenuController** which shows **cut, copy, paste, select, select all** menu.

Any one knows how to do it

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for UIMenuController is available here
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html

The UIMenuController is a sharedInstance, so you're able to access it from anywhere as follows:

```
UIMenuController* menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
```

The message you need to send it to hide it is as so:

```
// If you don't want it animated, use NO for the 2nd parameter
[menu setMenuVisible:NO animated:YES];
```

As for the exact context you wish to use this in, I don't know much about it, but this is ultimately how you hide a UIMenuController

Comment: @user1120133 If this was suitable for your needs, can you please accept the answer? Thank you